# ggplot2 list of spatialpolygonsdataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to use ggplot2 in R to plot multiple spatialpolygonsdataframe that are stored as objects in a list? Each index has a spatialpolygonsdataframe. There are 64 in total, all stored in shp. I want to plot all individual indexes on 1 map. All the data have the same attributes, just different IDs and areas.

example list:

```
hsp1<-getData("GADM", country="NZ", level=0)
sp2<-getData("GADM", country="US", level=0)
sp3<-getData("GADM", country="AU", level=0)
shp <- list(sp1, sp2, sp3)
```

Hope this is enough information

Comment: Do the data overlap? Could you combine them all into one polygon dataframe?

Comment: Some do but not all. I need to color them all differently as well, which is why I am hesitant to combine then into one spatialpolygondataframe. It is an option if all else fails though

Comment: Can you give a sample dataset? It doesn't have to be your data. It's hard to say without knowing if all the data have the same attributes etc. You should be able to combine your polygons to a single file using `do.call(rbind, c(makeUniqueIDs = TRUE, shp))`. From here you can use the ggplot color argument to color by your id column.

Comment: Thanks so much, that will work. It actually makes it simpler. All the data have the same attributes, just different IDs and areas. They are all 1 polygon. I edited my first question with some sample data.